# Why flask flash is not working?

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

This is my python view code. I have a flash in it. But it wont show any kind of flash front end.

```
  @auth.route('/admin/project/add',methods = ['POST', 'GET']) 
    def addproject():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            projectname = request.form['projectname']
            c, conn = connection()
            query = "SELECT Count(id) from projects WHERE project='{}'".format(projectname)
            c.execute(query)
            values = c.fetchall
            conn.close() 
            if (values == 0):
                flash("success")
                return render_template('addproject.html') 
            else:
                flash("Project already exists. Please goto projects page and confirm. If it is and error, please contact devloper.")
                return render_template('addproject.html') 
        else:        
            return render_template('addproject.html')
```

In template, I have added this :

```
{% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
         {% if messages %}
            <ul>
               {% for message in messages %}
               <li><{{ message }}</li>
               {% endfor %}
            </ul>
         {% endif %}
      {% endwith %}
```

Can someone help me with the issue?
This is also done:

```
from flask import flash, redirect, render_template, url_for, request
```

Comment: Typo Alert ! check the flash for-loop

Comment: I corrected it..still I am not getting the flash

Comment: then it may be related to the conditions, try to put a flash just before `if request.method == 'POST':` to check

Comment: I tried..it is not displaying anything

Comment: Html part also I checkd...

Comment: Does ```c.fetchall``` return 0? Try flashing any message at the top of the route and see if it works.

Comment: I tried in different route...still flash is not appearing

Comment: could you please add a small template that reproduces this issue ?

Comment: Ok i will add it

Answer (score 0):

it's needed to be executed : `projectname`

```
cur = conn.cursor()
query = """SELECT Count(id) from projects WHERE project= :project"""
cur.execute(query, project = projectname)
```

Comment: because it should be get data from request.form first, try it please